# How to select endorsing peers when submitting transaction in GO SDK

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have a Hyperledger-Fabric network with two organisations: Org1 and Org2. Discovery is enabled.
When I run a Gateway client and submit a transaction, it always be endorsed by peer0.peer.org1.com.
In particular scenario, I may want to select particular peer to endorse the transaction.

Noticed that there is a function in Go SDK, called channel.WithTargetEndpoints(), I thought that i could use this function to append RequestOption. When I used any target peers from org1, the transaction could be processed successfully, however, when I tried to specify peers from org2, it didnt work.
Guess my user certificate was signed by org1. NetworkPeerConfig can fetch the peer configuration based on a key (name or URL). However, user within org1 cannot fetch the peer configuration for org2's peers.

How to select endorsing peers when submitting transaction in GO SDK?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the gateway package to submit the transaction, then you should use [WithEndorsingPeers](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/blob/main/pkg/gateway/transaction.go#L71) as the optional argument.

Comment: No, it is the same, you can see from the submit function( func (txn *Transaction) Submit(args ...string) ), it also use 'channel.WithTargetEndpoints(txn.endorsingPeers...)' to create RequestOption which is exactly what i did before. however, it only works for the peer who is from the same organisation as gateway user is.    In my case, i may want to select specific peer from other organisation.